# Get attributes from a selected element in dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

If I have this HTML code:

```
<select id="selectSomething">
    <option id="4" data-name="tomato" data-email="tomato@t.com">Tomato</option>
    <option id="5" data-name="potato" data-email="potato@t.com">Potato</option>
</select>
```

And someone picks an option..

I then have this javascript code:

```
var $selectedValue = $("#selectSomething option:selected");
var somethingName = $selectedValue("data-name");
var somethingEmail = $selectedValue("data-email");
```

But for some reason I get an error: "Uncaught TypeError: $selectedValue is not a function"

What's wrong here, and how do I get this to work?

Comment: Exactly what it says on the tin. It's not a function. Youre trying to pass "data-name" to $selectedValue when all $selectedValue is is a selection not a function. What is it you're trying to do ?

Comment: What are you trying to do..?

Comment: @thisOneGuy I'm trying to create javascript variables to pass in the values for the selected option..

Comment: yeah many people solved below :)

Comment: @NickZuber so in essence, when the javascript code runs, if user selects the first option, I'll have the variable somethingName = "tomato", somethingEmail = "tomato@t.com"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$selectedValue` is a jQuery selector element. Getting a property out of this can be done with

```
var somethingName = $selectedValue.attr('data-name');
```

but in your case, it might be more appropriate to use `.data()` which is specifically invented for data- attributes

```
var somethingName = $selectedValue.data('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

> $selectedValue

isn't a function it is a jQuery object containing your elements.

you need to use

```
var somethingName = $selectedValue.Data("name");

var somethingEmail = $selectedValue.Data("email");
```

more examples can be found
https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Note that the method is `data()` not `Data()`